# How to write key(get,default) method?

Tags: python, dictionary

My code

```
def awsmatc(input_string):
    my_dict = {'ticr_calculated_2': 'ticr-2.parquet', 'ticr_calculated_3': 'ticr-3.parquet', \
               'ticr_calculated_4': 'ticr-4.parquet', 'tick_calculated_2': 'tick-2.parquet', \
               'tick_calculated_3': 'tick-3.parquet', 'tick_calculated_4': 'tick-4.parquet'}

    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if any(key in input_string):
            return value

i = 'tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T00-01-21.json'
awsmatc(i)
```

I want to compare every key with input string and if they match,choose the respective value.

I got

```
  File "scratch_3.py", line 7, in awsmatc
    if any(key in input_string):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

How to write dictionary get(key[, default]) method?  I prefer not to use regex pattern,it gets too slow when I compose the method later.

Comment: Why you need `any()` here? `key in input_string` should be sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key in input_string` returns bool. Now `any()` takes some iterable and work on it. That is why you are getting this error.

Try to remove `any()` in your code. That should serve your purpose.

```
def awsmatc(input_string):
    my_dict = {'ticr_calculated_2': 'ticr-2.parquet', 'ticr_calculated_3': 'ticr-3.parquet', \
               'ticr_calculated_4': 'ticr-4.parquet', 'tick_calculated_2': 'tick-2.parquet', \
               'tick_calculated_3': 'tick-3.parquet', 'tick_calculated_4': 'tick-4.parquet'}

    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if key in input_string:
            return value
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, if you want to find just one matching value, remove the `any` keyword. If you want to return a list of all values with a matching key, you can do it with a list comprehension:

```py
def awsmatc(input_string):
    my_dict = {'ticr_calculated_2': 'ticr-2.parquet', 'ticr_calculated_3': 'ticr-3.parquet', \
               'ticr_calculated_4': 'ticr-4.parquet', 'tick_calculated_2': 'tick-2.parquet', \
               'tick_calculated_3': 'tick-3.parquet', 'tick_calculated_4': 'tick-4.parquet'}

    return [value for key, value in my_dict.items() if key in input_string]

i = 'tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T00-01-21.json'
print(awsmatc(i))
```

As a sidenote, it might be better for you to define your dictionary outside of the function, to stop it from being redefined and then garbage-collected every time your function is called.